# PowerBI : ModelObjectUri component is not specified for Column

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

When click "Refresh all" in powerbi desktop, error pop up
"ModelObjectUri component is not specified for Column"

Anyone has idea on how to resolve the issue?

Is this issue raised due to PBI version Dec 2023?
The PBI works well before the version change.